# Single resource and multiple resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model Whitelabel and a User has_many :whitelables

I have a custom method current_whitelabel (like authlogic or restful_auth for current_user)

I want my users to manage their whitelabels (ie: edit_whitelabels_path(id)).

But I don't want to send the whitelabel ID in params when it refers to the current_whitelabel.

So my idea is to create two resources: map.resources whitelabels and map.resource whitelabel.

But I don't like this so much. Is there any sexier way to accomplish it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally solved my problem.

Each whitelabel has his own subdomain (thanks to subdomain_fu), so I just need a single resource whitelabel in my routes to do action on my current_whitelabel and if I want to do action on others whitelabels, I just have to switch the subdomain.

Thanks EmFi for trying to answer to my strange question.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller action you can do this:

```
class WhitelabelsController < ActionController
  def edit
    @whitelabel = params[:id] ?  Whitelabel.find(params[:id]) : current_whitelabel
    redirect_to whitelabels_url unless @whitelabel
    ....
  end
  ...
end
```

Now rails will treat `/whitelabel/edit` as `/whitelabel/edit/#{current_whitelabel.id}` without specifying the id.

If this happens for more than one action you can do it as a before filter. Just be sure to remove all `@whitelabel = Whitelable.find(params[:id])` lines from the individual actions.

```
class WhitelabelsController < ActionController
  before_filter :select_whitelabel, :except => [:index, :new]

  def select_whitelabel
    @whitelabel = params[:id] ?  Whitelabel.find(params[:id]) : current_whitelabel
    redirect_to whitelabels_url unless @whitelabel
  end
  ...
end
```

Answering the more clearly stated question in the comment:
You can use a singular resource in tandem with the above code to have the effect you want.

**config/routes.rb**

```
map.resource :my_whitelabel, :controller => "whitelabels", :member => {:dashboard => :get}
```

Then in the whitelabels controller use the above code. This keeps things DRY by using the same controller for different paths with the same actions. The resource defines a dashboard action, so you'll have to add that to the controller too. But if you're using the before_filter version there should be no problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer EmFi, but it doesn't answer to my question. 
Maybe my question is not clear.
I have some actions for all whitelabels but some which are just for the current one.
so I need two types of urls:
/whitelabels/id/action for all user's whitelabels.
And something like /my_current_whitelabel/dashboard.
Do I have to do two different resources to do that ?

Comment: Your question was definitely not clear. I've updated my answer to give a solution to the problem mentioned in your comment.

Comment: Ok, thanks EmFi I thought that there was a more rails way to do this but maybe not. So I will do named route.

Comment: I jumped the gun with the named_route, and revised the answer to a more DRY and robust approach

Comment: Ok EmFi, after a long night, I am going to develop my whitelabels system and I realized that your solution is to create TWO new routes : a single one and a multiple one. Exactly what I don't want to do ... But maybe there is no other way.

Comment: I know you're using subdomains to set the current whitelabel, but... out of curiosity, what is wrong with having two routes?